# Makefile throws missing separator error on a different machine

Tags: makefile

When I ran Makefile on one Ubuntu machine the compilation went all fine. However, when I run it on another way, I get the error.

*** missing separator

Can the type of machine cause this error?

Comment: can you show your Makefile

Comment: I'll answer the question you asked because there's not enough information for anything more substantial: assuming both systems are using GNU make, then _no_, the type of machine cannot cause this error.

Comment: Plausible explanation is that makefile on the failing machine had a history that involved being saved from an editor configured to convert tabs to spaces.